# How to set symbolic breakpoint for initWithNibName in Xcode

Tags: debugging, xcode10.1, symbolic-breakpoint

How to set breakpoint in xcode 10.1 to break when the method 
`[initWithNibName: bundle:]` is called in Objective-C?

I can set breakpoint for `-[UIViewController viewDidLoad]` but don't know how to do with initWithNibName.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
-[UIViewController initWithNibName:]
-[UIViewController initWithNibName: bundle:]
-[UIContentContainer initWithNibName:]
-[UIContentContainer initWithNibName: bundle:]
```

I don't want to over-write the initWithNibName for every CustomUIViewController then set breakpoint for each class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use any space when writing the method signature. It should be:

```
-[UIViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It works like a charm. Save me a lot of time. :D